# Standard error of dummy coded within factor in a linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, standard-error

I try to use a linear mixed model to test a difference hypothesis of a within subject design. The design has one within factor with 11 different levels (nominal). One of this level is considered the control condition and I want to compare all other condition vs. the control condition. Therefore, I specified it as reference level and used an effect coding. The dependent measurement is on an interval level.

Therefore i specified the following linear mixed effects model:

```
value ~ within.factor + (1|subject)
```

I added the random factor to account for subject variability.
When I look at the results of the model, it all looks fine and plausible, but what really wonders me, are the standard errors of the dummy coded predictors:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.01687    0.01102  -1.530  0.12744    
Var2a2      -0.02152    0.01559  -1.380  0.16904    
Var2a3      -0.11179    0.01559  -7.170 1.27e-11 ***
Var2a4       0.02118    0.01559   1.358  0.17580    
Var2a5      -0.02218    0.01559  -1.423  0.15625    
Var2a6       0.01788    0.01559   1.147  0.25276    
Var2a7       0.01802    0.01559   1.156  0.24914    
Var2a8       0.02882    0.01559   1.849  0.06593 .  
Var2a9      -0.04253    0.01559  -2.728  0.00692 ** 
Var2a10     -0.04405    0.01559  -2.825  0.00518 ** 
Var2a11      0.01922    0.01559   1.233  0.21909
```

Why is every single standard error the same? Shouldn't they be different, since the variance in each within factor is also different? Or does the model assume equal variance in all levels of the factor and therefore sets the to a specific value?

Comment: Yes, it assumes equal variance.